# IE (internet exploder) ajax issue with json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer, google-custom-search

Okay i've bashed my head over this enough so I'm resorting to asking the hive :p

I'm using google custom searches rest api with jquery to get results and build out the results for the browser

the issue I'm having is in ie this function does nothing i get a jqXHR response of 0 i checked in ie's debug bar and when looking at network traffic its attempting to hit "https:///" instead of the url provided in the ajax call can anyone please help me in solving this?

Specifics:
IE Version: 8 (i know my company is retorted don't ask...)

Code:

```
//init varables for getResults
var currentIndex;
var nextIndex;
var prevIndex;
var totalResults;

var urlParams = parseParamsFromUrl();
var queryParamName = "q";

function getResults(startIndex) {

    //clear results for new dataset
    $('.results').html('');

    //      debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1',
        data: {
            key: 'AIzaSyBsiF3yLVphOd6c74PYOA-02iJx6dlmQuI',
            cx: '003411025563286140424:apyyekjazdi',
            q: urlParams[queryParamName],
            start: startIndex
        },
        success: function (data) {

            //set some variables for later use.
            currentIndex = data.queries.request[0]['startIndex'];
            nextIndex = data.queries.nextPage[0]['startIndex'];
            totalResults = data.searchInformation.totalResults;

            //              debugger;

            //if there are 0 results return nothing found
            if (totalResults === '0') {
                $('.results').html('<h3 class="three column centered">No results found!</h3>');
            }

            //check if theres more than 10 results to show the next button
            if (totalResults > 10) {
                $('.next').removeClass('hide');
            }

            if (currentIndex !== 1) {
                prevIndex = data.queries.previousPage[0]['startIndex'];
            }

            //if current index is 1 hide previous button
            if (currentIndex > 1) {
                $('.prev').removeClass('hide');
            } else {
                $('.prev').addClass('hide');
            }

            //hide query status
            $('.resultspinner').hide();

            //loop through all promotion results and add before regulars
            var promoresult;
            if (typeof data.promotions != 'undefined') {

                //show promotions div
                $('.promotions').show();

                $.each(data.promotions, function (index, value) {
                    //check if promotion has a description if so set it in the result
                    var promotionbody;

                    if (typeof value.bodyLines !== 'undefined') {
                        promotionbody = value.bodyLines['0']['htmlTitle'];
                    } else {
                        promotionbody = '';
                    }

                    //check if result has an image if so show in results if not display default
                    if (typeof value.image == 'undefined') {
                        var thumbnail = '\n\
                           <div class="thumb-box three column"> \n\
                                <a href="' + value.link + '">\n\
                                    <img src="http://www.insp.com/wp-content/themes/insp_foundation/images/thumbnail.jpg" />\n\
                                </a>\n\
                            </div>';
                    } else {
                        var thumbnail = '\n\
                           <div class="thumb-box three column"> \n\
                                <a href="' + value.link + '">\n\
                                    <img width="120" src="' + value.image.source + '" />\n\
                                </a>\n\
                            </div>';
                    }

                    //build layout for result
                    var promoresult = '\n\
                        <div class="search-result row promotion" id="post-' + index + '">\n\
                                   ' + thumbnail + '\n\
                    \n\
                        <div class="post-entry nine columns" >\n\
                            <h3 class="posttitle">\n\
                                <a href="' + value.link + '"> ' + value.title + '</a>\n\
                            </h3>\n\
                            \n\
                            <div class="entry">\n\
                                ' + promotionbody + '\n\
                            </div>\n\
                        </div>';
                    $('.promotions').append(promoresult);
                });
                //                    $('.promotions').prepend('<h4>Promotions: </h4>');
            }

            //loop through all regular results
            $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
                //check if result has an image if so show in results if not display default
                if (typeof value.pagemap.metatags['0']['og:image'] == 'undefined') {
                    var thumbnail = '\n\
                           <div class="thumb-box three column"> \n\
                                <a href="' + value.link + '">\n\
                                    <img src="http://www.insp.com/wp-content/themes/insp_foundation/images/thumbnail.jpg" />\n\
                                </a>\n\
                            </div>';
                } else {
                    var thumbnail = '\n\
                           <div class="thumb-box three column"> \n\
                                <a href="' + value.link + '">\n\
                                    <img width="120" src="' + value.pagemap.metatags['0']['og:image'] + '" />\n\
                                </a>\n\
                            </div>';
                }

                //build layout for result
                var result = '\n\
                        <div class="search-result row result" id="post-' + index + '">\n\
                                   ' + thumbnail + '\n\
                    \n\
                        <div class="post-entry nine columns" >\n\
                            <h3 class="posttitle">\n\
                                <a href="' + value.link + '"> ' + value.pagemap.metatags[0]['og:title'] + '</a>\n\
                            </h3>\n\
                            \n\
                            <div class="entry">\n\
                                ' + value.htmlSnippet + '\n\
                            </div>\n\
                        </div>';


                //set data to result
                $('.results').append(result);

            });
            //                $('.results').prepend('<h4>Results: </h4>');

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: Brace yourself! *Internet Exploder*....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out IE in all its failtasticness completely ignores any cross domain ajax requests regardless if there allowed are not you MUST use server side alternatives to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure you can't use AJAX to get a file on a different domain. You would have to call a server-side script on your server, which itself calls the API and retuns the data.

Comment: this works in all other browsers though, i can do it server side but If it works in everything else it should work here, also you can do remote domain calls with ajax assuming they have domain-origin access set to allow remote calls which i would hope that google would have done.

Comment: Well, maybe IE8 is complaining about the HTTPS target if your site isn't HTTPS. Or maybe it just doesn't support cross-domain stuff (I don't know - never tried it)